# Video not autoplaying

Tags: html, css, html5-video, magnific-popup

I cannot seem to get the video to autoplay I've choose not to use video attribute as I wanted the static image to look nicer before the video is played.

to get the video to play I need to click the play button than a small thumbnail of the video appears. I then need to click on the small thumbnail in order for the video to play. On chrome browser on desktop or laptop it seems to work fine and play back with no problems with on mobile devices and safari it requires this action and will not just autoplay.

```css
  .why-choose {
  background: #fff;
}

.why-choose .choose-right {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('img/video-bg.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
}

.why-choose .choose-right .video {
  color: #fff;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -35px;
  margin-top: -35px;
  font-size: 21px;
  background: #1a76d1;
  padding-left: 4px;
}

.why-choose .choose-right .video:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.why-choose .video-image .waves-block .waves {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: waves 3s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: waves 3s ease-in-out infinite;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -100px;
}

.why-choose .video-image .waves-block .wave-1 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.why-choose .video-image .waves-block .wave-2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.why-choose .video-image .waves-block .wave-3 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  .mfp-iframe-holder .mfp-close {
    color: #FFF;
    right: -6px;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 6px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .mfp-iframe-holder {
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
  }
  .mfp-iframe-holder .mfp-content {
    line-height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 900px;
  }
  .mfp-iframe-holder .mfp-close {
    top: -40px;
  }
  .mfp-iframe-scaler {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 56.25%;
  }
  .mfp-iframe-scaler iframe {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    background: #000;
  }
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-12">
  <!-- Start Choose Rights -->
  <div class="choose-right">
    <div class="video-image">
      <!-- Video Animation -->
      <div class="promo-video">
        <div class="waves-block">
          <div class="waves wave-1"></div>
          <div class="waves wave-2"></div>
          <div class="waves wave-3"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/ End Video Animation -->
      <a href="video/emergency-plumber-bristol.mp4" class="video video-popup mfp-iframe"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End Choose Rights -->
</div>
```

Comment: the browser policy don't allow autoplay wideo with sound, try to add mute attribute to your  video tag

Comment: as mentioned in the description I've not used the video attribute. But thanks for reponse.

Comment: when you click on the thumbnail what happen? how you play video without video tag?

Comment: On which systems is it not playing automatically? On my IOS/iPad clicking play on an a element with href plays it immediately.

Comment: @IgorZinchenko using <a> element bootstrap/css3 and magnetic-popup CDN.

Comment: @AHaworth they all work I just want it to autoplay when clicking the play button rather than having to click the play button.